# Fluent Configuration, ignore property based on decorated attribute

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I have a need to ignore properties based on attribute.

Below you will see some code (a small extract of my project) and you will get a feel for what I am trying to accomplish.

What I am struggling with is to add this rule to my bhibernate configureation, ie, if a property has a `[IgnoreProperty]` attribute flientnhibernate should not include it in the schema being generated.

I would like to have this as generic as possible so I do not have to create a class map for every entity.

Is there any way to include this sort of functionality directly into the Configuration? if so, I would really appreciate an example

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Surname { get; set; }

    [IgnoreProperty]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.Name, this.Surname); }
    }
}

public class IgnorePropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class SessionManager
{
    private static ISessionFactory GetFactory()
    {
        return
        Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile(Path.Combine(@"C:\temp","MyDatabaseName.db")))
            .Mappings(
            m =>
            m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Person>(t => t.Namespace.StartsWith(typeof(Person).Namespace))))
            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See this [page](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping#wiki-ignoring-properties) for more information.

You can ignore properties by using predicate

```
.OverrideAll(map =>  
{  
  map.IgnoreProperties(x => x.Name.Contains("Something"));
});
```

Just modify the predicate to use reflection to find out if there's an attribute defined.

Update:
This can be used in `ClassMap`s. In order to apply the convention globally apply a convention implementing `IPropertyConventionAcceptance` interface (see [this](http://marcinobel.com/index.php/fluent-nhibernate-conventions-examples/) or [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/ysa/2011/02/05/defining-acceptance-criteria-for-mapping-conventions-in-nhibernate/)):

```
public MyConvetion : IPropertyConventionAcceptance 
{
  public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
  {
    criteria.Expect(x => boolValue); // [is there a IgnoreAttribute]);
  }
}
```

[This](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Conventions) page tells you more about conventions and how to apply them globally.

Comment: as mentioned in my question, I am not sure how to add this to my fluent configuration. this is a section of code that has no reference as to where to add it, nor does it show anything on how to configure `OverideAll` for attribute identification.

Comment: `Fluently.Configure().Mappings(m => { m.FluentMappings.Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<LowercaseTableNameConvention>(); })`

Answer (score 0):

The following code will prevent the column from generating in your database. Don't forget to add the configuration to your mapping.

```
public class AutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(Member member)
    {
        if (member.MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IgnorePropertyAttribute), true).Length > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return base.ShouldMap(member);
    }
}
```